# Gmail wraps some text in email as a link by default

Tags: html, gmail

For example 
test.net in html will be

```
 <a href="http://test.net">test.net</a>
```

Hot can I disable this wrapping?

Comment: There seems to be at least a few questions on this exact topic already here.

Comment: Can you give a link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preventing gmail from stripping href, target, and id attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416676/preventing-gmail-from-stripping-href-target-and-id-attributes)