# Gmail removes links' href attributes

Tags: email, hyperlink, gmail, mustache

I need to use Mustache variables in links' href attributes in my email template.
`<a href="{{var}}">Link</a>`
That works properly in all email clients and web versions except Gmail which removes href attributes. But when I try to hard code the value, everything becomes fine. Have anybody faced this problem and is there any way to solve it not avoiding using Mustache? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416676/preventing-gmail-from-stripping-href-target-and-id-attributes