# Gmail strips href in my hyperlink using PHP Mailer

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer

so i using php mailer to send email. The email was sent. When i open that email on http://temp-mail.org, the hyperlink is working. But when i open it on gmail, gmail strip my href.

Here is my code:

```
\Mail::send([], [], function ($message){
     $message->from('email@from.com', 'Email From');
     message->to('email@to.com');

     $body = '<a href="https://google.co.id">Check this link</a>';
     $message->setBody($body, 'text/html');
});
```

it's work on temp-mail, but on gmail it only return:

```
<a>Check this link</a>
```

At the end of email i got this:

Privileged/confidential information may be contained in this message. If you are not the named recipient or addressee, you are hereby notified that any use review, disclosure or copying of the contents herein is strictly prohibited. In such a case, kindly discard all its contents and notify sender accordingly regarding such unauthorized disclosure or transmission by email. Opinions, conclusions, statements and other information in this message that do not relate to the official business of //Sender shall be understood as neither given or endorsed by it. The contents herein are meant strictly for the use of the named recipient or addressee of //Sender. No assumption of responsibility or liability whatsoever is undertaken by //Sender in respect of prohibited and unauthorised use by any other person.

Comment: sorry, i got typo on my question, have tried the correct one, still not working. updated my question

Comment: `$body = "<a href=\"https://google.co.id\">Click Here</a>";`  Check this

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: What does `$body` contain ?

Comment: `'<a href="https://google.co.id">Check this link</a>'` this, the link i would to send

Comment: i never got this problem before, all working fine before, i got this problem just today

Comment: Can you check with empty content. I think the issue is with your content only might be privacy or some policy issue. check with other urls

Comment: i have tried using my original webite url, still doesn't work

Comment: @AlfaritsiHamdani Maybe google's gmail is reading `Check this link` and finding it to be suspicious. Can you change the text and try something else?

Comment: Yes i have tried it

Comment: @AlfaritsiHamdani You need to tag, else I won't be notified. What did you try?

Comment: @vivek_23 ah, sorry. I have tried changed it to my website name, lorem ipsum text, none of that work

Comment: @AlfaritsiHamdani Ok, can you change the email address in `$message->from('email@from.com', 'Email From');` and try again?

Comment: @vivek_23, yes i have tried it too. change to 2 different account of gmail, none of that work. change to 5 different account of temp-mail, all of that work

Comment: @AlfaritsiHamdani ok, Google is a bit suspicious about your link `https://google.co.id`. Can you change the link and try? Meanwhile, [does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416676/preventing-gmail-from-stripping-href-target-and-id-attributes) ?

Comment: @vivek_23 changed it to `<a href="https://youtube.com">Click It</a>`. still the same

Comment: @AlfaritsiHamdani It is purely a Google security check that strips the link. I think Google has blacklisted your email address and many other associated data(like IP etc) to prevent malicious emails(as it thinks that way about your emails).

Comment: @vivek_23 i think so, i just try using my personal gmail account for smtp, and it works. I will check it. Thank you for helping...

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue and had resorted to sending links and other elements as plain text. But in my case, the positioning of `$mail->AltBody` was causing the problem.

My configuration was initially like this:

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $body_html;
$mail->AltBody = $body_plain;
```

But once I changed the order to `AltBody`, `Body`, `isHTML`, I was able to deliver HTML buttons and links without issue:

```
$mail->AltBody = $body_plain;
$mail->Body = $body_html;
$mail->isHTML(true);
```